# converting cups of rice to kilos

Tags: rice, bulk-cooking

Planning to cook rice for 200 people--will be using long grain rice and slow cooking in the oven.  How many cups of rice do I need?  How many kilos of long grain rice do I need.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, rookie! As written, your question is too vague--how much rice to feed to people depends on a variety of factors, such as their age, the type of meal (e.g. breakfast at a hotel vs. lunch on a hiking trip), whether the rice is a side, a dish component, or the only food...

Comment: will be served at a shelter --adding peas and carrots to it and will be served under honey garlic meatballs

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/60032/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7068/67

Comment: @mech : it's not an unreasonable question.  It's similar to  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75505/67 .  We just need to know if this is a side or part of the main dish, and is this lunch, dinner or something else (which he followed up with)

Comment: @Joe : without the follow-up, which I prompted, it was too vague. I did not call it unreasonable.

Comment: @mech : we're going to disagree here ... with too much detail, the question is more easily answered, but it makes it so it's less likely to help someone else in the future.  A certain level of vagueness can be good

Answer (score 1):

If you cook rice for 200 people you could consider 100 grams per person so a total of 20kg.
I'm making a lot of assumptions here, I know, like I have no idea what your other servings look like.

As a general piece of advice and as semi-professional chef, I'd recommend to use grams at all times. Cups is a volume-based measurements and rice has a lot of air around it, and its volume will depend on the type of rice, temperature of the environment in which you measure and even humidity! If you go pro, you should resort to using accurate weight-measurements rather than volume-units.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you have to qualify 'cups', as a 'cup' for rice cookers is 175mL but an Imperial 'cup' is 284mL (250mL for "metric cup", 237mL for US traditional cup) ... so they're even messier when asking on websites