# Risotto preparation

Tags: risotto

If I was going to prepare 100 portions of a basic risotto part way to finish later on in saute pans for different flavours, how would I go about doing this? What would I cook a large batch in, would a stock pot be suitable? How many kilos of rice could I cook in one go for best results?

Also side question, could I make a vegetable stock in a tea urn and have stock on tap?

Comment: What portion size are you aiming for?

Comment: related/partial duplicate https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/how-do-cooks-prepare-risotto-in-a-restaurant?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, most (*) restaurant will prepare risotto in advance, will prepare the basic recipe and undercook it a little bit; cool it quickly and portion it put in the fridge/freezer and then when ready to serve, they reheat and add flavouring.

See this : 
http://www.seriouseats.com/2017/05/how-to-make-ahead-risotto.html

Is the risotto used for a side dish, look for about 50-ish grams or a main dish 120-ish grams for the rice; do a test in advance to see if you need more or less rice (from what I can find on the internets)

So about 5 KG to 12KG of rice.

As for the cooking vessels, I'd use as large a pan that can fit your cooktop and do multiple small batches, will be easier to put on a pan and cool down.

I'd go for about 500 grams per batch, again, test in advance to see if it fits your pan. You should be able to easily stir the rice and add the liquid.

Comment: You'd want to have as many pans as you needed for cooling the risotto ... so potentially you could split a batch between multiple pans for cooling.